# Python 3 how to add a single value to multi dimension array column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let say this is the original list

```
a = [['john', 12, 15],
     ['keith', 8, 20],
     ['jane', 18, 10]]
```

I want to add a value `99` to each row, the expected result will be like

```
a = [['john', 12, 15, 99],
     ['keith', 8, 20, 99],
     ['jane', 18, 10, 99]]
```

Any build in function to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this:

```
a = [x + [99] for x in a]
```

Btw. what you are using is a python `list`, not an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to *modify your existing lists* then simply loop and append:

```
for l in a:
    l.append(99)
```

If you are fine with *creating new lists* then use the list-comprehension suggested by @languitar.